# map::const_iterator to map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a Map::const_iterator object in C++ and i am trying to abstract the entire map object from it without explicitly creating a map with Map::const_iterator->first and Map::const_iterator->second.

this doesn't seem to work : (*Map::const_iterator).as_map()
please advice.

Comment: I am almost sure (*Map::const_iterator) should give you a instance of  pair<Key,Value>, and pair<,> does not have a as_map() method.

Comment: Map is <String,Map>. I want to copy this map from the iterator without having to create a copy of the map.

Comment: (*Map::const_iterator) also did not seem to work.

Comment: What error do you get if you write `iter->as_map()`? Is your `as_map` method declared const?

Comment: You need to post the definition of Map and String etc. etc. And you need to post what you tried and the error messages you get. You can see that you've already confused several people who think that your Map is the same as std::map. Remember we can't see what you can see.

Comment: "Map is <String,Map>" doesn't make sense. What's the exact type ? Which of your types has an `as_map` member function ?

Comment: Aha... you want a Map of Maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid I understood the question totally wrong. How about using it->second?

```
 typedef .... mymap_t;
 typedef std::map<std::string, mymap_t> supermap_t;

 supermap_t supermap;


 for (supermap_t::const_iterator it = supermap.begin();
          it != supermap.end();
          ++it)
 {
     const mymap& the_sub_map = it->second;
     call_some_other_function(the_sub_map); // the whole submap
 }
```

<strike><sub>From the question it is hard to make out what you actually need, but I'm going to guess that you are looking for a way to treat an iterator range as a container, without having to copy the container.</sub></strike>

Have a look at [Boost Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/introduction.html) for that.

```
 typedef map<int, string> mymap_t;

 mymap_t mymap;
 mymap[1] = "One";
 mymap[2] = "Two";
 mymap[3] = "Three";

 mymap_t::const_iterator first(my_map.begin()), 
                         last(my_map.end());

 boost::sub_range<mymap_t> subrange(first++, last); // contains two items
```

You could treat `subrange` as a 'container' class with boost range algorithms.

Does this come close to what you wanted to ask?

#### Update

It seems you are after this:

```
 typedef map<int, string> mymap_t;

 void somefunction(mymap_t::const_iterator first, mymap_t::const_iterator last)
 {
     mymap_t subclone(first, last);

     // use subclone -- it is a mymap_t now :)
 } 

 mymap_t mymap;
 mymap[1] = "One";
 mymap[2] = "Two";
 mymap[3] = "Three";

 somefunction(mymap.begin(), mymap.end());
```

Comment: Well somewhat. I want the output to be a map object. So for your code, I need access to the map mymap_t using the mymap_t::const_iterator. Something like:

for(mymap_t::const_iterator itr = mymap.begin(); itr != mymap.end(); mymap++) 
{
send_to_some_function(*itr);
}

where this *itr should be the entire mymap_t object.

Comment: See also a working demo on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/IvSjfV4J) (_slow today...?_) and [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/uEvmE)

Comment: Mmmm.. I think I might have got the real question this time. Feel free to skim the 'striked' text as well, in case my earlier interpretation of the question was still better  :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any sense the way you explained it.

A Map::const_iterator is defined within the Map class.  It shouldn't be able to exist without the map class as its defined based on the internal implementation of Map.

You can cycle though the map using the const_iterator and .first .second to get the entire contents from the map if you like, but you can't pretend the map isn't there in the first place.

If you are looking to make a function that can take an arbitrary iterator and container and process them then you wouldn't want to use .first and .second because maps are the only STL container that has those members since they work on pairs.  You could get around this problem somewhat by making a template specialization detailing what to do with specific types.

So your normal template code would handle any type, but if it were a map, your specialization could handle it and use .first and .second specifically, and only in that case.  If you're going down this road though you'll need a specialization for every type of map you use for the algorithm your making - you should probably rethink your design in that case and go down a different road :(